# How input Value from Scanner, and output the value to an txt file in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, file, command-line-interface

I'm struggling to input value from Scanner option in Java to a txt file. while I can smoothly read the data using try{} catch{}, I cannot write the data from a scanner to the txt file. I can easily write data to txt file using PrintWriter, but that's not my goal... According to the scenario of the assignment, I have to create the system to input values and store the data text file, which I'm struggling to do.

Please help me with this problem, and provide me a solution...
This is my first Java project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String data = sc.nextLine(); //taking input from user

// Use try with resource to release system resources
try ( FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("filename.txt"); ) {
  myWriter.write(data); //writing into file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say you have successfully read (and maybe also manipulated) the data. Lets assume you have it ready to be written out as a `String data` and you also have a String `filename` of the file's intended name.

You can then do the following:

```
// generate the File object
File f = Paths.get("./" + filename).toFile();
        
f.delete(); // remove previous existing file -- equivalent to overwrite
try(BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f))){
    wr.append(data); // adding the data into write buffer
    wr.flush(); // writing the data out to the file
    wr.close(); // closing the buffered writer
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```